# Open an external link in an iframe page in Drupal CMS?

Tags: php, iframe, drupal, rss, feed

I am developing a news aggregator site which gets rss feed links from other popular sites and displays in the site (http://news.anytime.in).
I would like to open those links in a iframe page with my site header for easy navigation. As on now, it directly goes to the targeted site. Is it possible to do like that?
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Either you open the feeds in a Iframe, so if you open them they will stay in there, but you might have issues resizing your frame, or you have to add a target attribute to the feeds links with the name of an iframe already in your page (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_target.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an existing Drupal module for doing that, but here is a tutorial on [Implementing an iFrame Toolbar](http://www.amirharel.com/2009/07/28/implementing-iframe-toolbar/). You should be able to [add the necessary jQuery/Javascript to your theme or to a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/304255).